# Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, xml

Using the following code Handle JSON web serivce:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            String data = HttpDataHandler.GetHTTPData(rootURL);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("arrKitchenAPP");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String submenu_Pk_id = jsonObject1.optString("PK_ID");
                    String submenu_name = jsonObject1.optString("Submenu_name");
                    String submenu_image = jsonObject1.optString("Submenu_image");
                    String submenu_displayOrder = jsonObject1.optString("Display_order");
                    String submenu_mainMenuFkId = jsonObject1.optString("Main_menu_fkid");

                    Model model = new Model();
                    model.setsubmenu_pk_id(submenu_Pk_id);
                    model.setSubmenu_name(submenu_name);
                    model.setSubmenu_image(submenu_image);
                    model.setDisplay_order(submenu_displayOrder);
                    model.setMain_menu_fkid(submenu_mainMenuFkId);

                }
```

While parsing Output am getting is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"arrKitchenAPP":[{"PK_ID":1,"Submenu_name":"Soups","Submenu_image":" ","Display_order":1,"Main_menu_fkid":1}]}</string>
```

I dont want the XML tag(). Need directly the Array. I don't know how to remove the XML values in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using .asmx service.I encountered this problem and here is how i solved it on service side

1) Declare a method for converting json and removing namespace title

```
private void ConvertJSON(object data)
    {

   Context.Response.Clear();
   Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
   Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented));

    }
```

then just use it.Here is a example

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void getCampaignList()
    {
        //GET JSON DATA and Convert it 


        ConvertJSON(response);
    }
```